# How to turn off insert of ASCII control characters using [control]+[option]+[key]

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut

I've tracked down the source of [a minor annoyance in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056391/xcode-invalid-character-in-source-file-replace-with) to the inadvertent introduction of invisible ASCII control characters using the key combination [control] + [option] + some key. However, I have no idea how to turn this feature off. I'd be totally ok if the [control]+[option] + whatever combination just did nothing.